# creating data type in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created several static methods that return List> so throughout my class you will find something like:

```
Future<List<List<dynamic>> initialiseStartupFile({@required bool isAssetFile}) {
// code
etc...
```

is there a way to change this to :

Future ?

```
can I create this DataTypeINeedToUse ?
```

I am new to flutter and dart

Comment: Hope [this](https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-typedef) will be useful for you..

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you are asking for, but if you want to change the data type to a Future dynamic type, just do this:

`Future<dynamic>`

Comment: is there a way to say :
DataTypeIWant = List<List<dynamic>>

I need that because I want to make it clear when I am using futureprovider

Comment: Well, it is not possible to assign a value to a variable with another data type. You cannot go like: ```String myString = 42``` Alternatively you can create a custom data type with a constructer which can convert a data type of ```List<List<dynamic>>``` to ```dataTypeIWant``` Ultimatively you have to make a function which converts the data type

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a new Class like this:

```
void main() async {
  DataTypeINeedToUse data = await getResult();
  data.list.forEach((el) => print("Hello ${el.hello} !"));
}

Future<DataTypeINeedToUse> getResult() {
  return Future.delayed(
    const Duration(seconds: 5),
    () => DataTypeINeedToUse([
      DataObject("camillo"),
      DataObject("luca"),
      DataObject("paolo"),
    ]),
  );
}

class DataTypeINeedToUse {
  List<DataObject> list;

  DataTypeINeedToUse(this.list);
}

class DataObject {
  String hello;

  DataObject(this.hello);
}
```